# RESTful data sources ETL to AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, etl, aws-glue

I am at the very beginning of a project where I need to load data from 3 separate SAAS services to a data warehouse on AWS. Each of the 3 SAAS applications offer open RESTful APIs to retrieve data.

The requirement is to extract data from these web services and load to a new data warehouse in AWS.  The limitation is that there doesn't appear to be any off-the-shelf API connectors in AWS Glue.

So, in short, are there any GNU ETL tools that run in AWS that can connect to an external API for extraction purposes (GET methods) and then to the transform and load to a cloud-based data warehouse?

As a side note, we're not married to AWS, so if there is a solution in Azure or any other IAAS companies that would be considered.

I've only done diligence at this point.  I'm looking into cloud data warehouse options with ETL tools that support REST API extraction.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like Amazon AppFlow - https://aws.amazon.com/appflow/  From the docs "Amazon AppFlow can directly extract data from some Services and it is directly integrated with AWS Glue DataBrew for Data Preparation and transformation."

You don't say what SAAS offerings you are using or what the data movement model you are desiring so this may not be the best option.  There are many data ingestion options at AWS.